# Issue styling a rails select box with boolean values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tried to find what I'm looking for on Stack but to no avail, Im trying to add a custom style class to a select form field in rails but am striking out.. can someone help me out please?

```
<%= f.select(:allow_profile_update_no_pw, options_for_select([['Active', true], ['Inactive', false]], {:selected => current_user.allow_profile_update_no_pw, :class => "someClass"}),:prompt => "Select") %>
```

This is the error i get when i place it in any of the {}

```
wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)
```

moving outside of those I cant get any results.

Comment: @MarkMerritt i just need to know where i can add a `:style => "someClass"` to this select field, ive tried to put it everywhere but i keep getting options errors I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` method is defined like this

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

In your case, you need to move `class` key-value pair to the next argument, i.e., under `html_options`, also with some other fixes, it should look like this

```
<%= f.select :allow_profile_update_no_pw, options_for_select([['Active', true], ['Inactive', false]], current_user.allow_profile_update_no_pw),{ :prompt => "Select"}, { :class => "someClass" } %>
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

Comment: Thank-you for this! i see where i went wrong, and thank you for the link! these select boxes always get me..